# RSocket not sending after 500 messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, rsocket

Using a fresh project downloaded from Spring Initializr with RSocket, I am experiencing an issue attempting to send fire-and-forget messages asynchronously. I can send and receive any number of messages below 500, but once I attempt to send the 500th, or any message afterwards, they are not received. From the logs, it seems it has to do with Netty's 500 maximum connections in the connection pool, but, shouldn't RSocket be returning these connections back to Netty once the message is sent? Especially when using `retrieveMono(Void.class)`?

Comment: Do you close resources correctly?

Comment: Is there a specific method to close resources for a single message? I was under the impression from multiple tutorials that there was no housekeeping to be done past sending the message and retrieving the Mono<Void>.

Comment: I don't know.  It is common, however, that close() is used to release an expensive resource.  Look for autoclosables to do this easily and safely.